# More than one seperator in a CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv

In my CSV file, headers are seperated by comma(,) and rows are seperated by semicolon(;). How could I clean the data?

All values are stored in first column and other rows are showing empty values.

Comment: It would help to see some of the data. Are there line breaks in the file in addition to semicolons or is it one long line with only semicolons to separate lines?

Answer (score 1):

Read the header row first with `scan`, then the table with `read.table`, setting `skip = 1`. Finally, assign the header names.

```
flname <- "so.txt"

header <- scan(flname, what = character(), sep = ",", nlines = 1L)
df1 <- read.table(flname, skip = 1L, sep = ";", header = FALSE)
names(df1) <- header

df1
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    a    1 1.23
#2    b    2 2.34
#3    c    3 3.45
```

---

## Data

The file `so.txt` contents are

```
col1,col2,col3
a;1;1.23
b;2;2.34
c;3;3.45
```